# How to check if a value already exists in an array and remove that from array in react js?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting

I am creating an app with react js and it has a function to add data into an array. Now I need to check if a value already exists in an array.
I have an array in state variable like this "Question: []".
My array data like below and "QuesID","OpId","option" has different values.

```
[
{"QType":"Rating","QuesID":20,"OpId":1,"option":1},
{"QType":"Rating","QuesID":21,"OpId":1,"option":1},
]
```

if I send data {"QType":"Rating","QuesID":20,"OpId":2,"option":1} like this need to remove the previous value from an array and add this new value to an array.

**This is what I tried,**

```
addData= (event, item) => {
    var QType = "Rating";
    var QuesID = "22";
    var OpId = "1";
    var option = "1";
    
    var Qobj = { QType: QType, QuesID: QuesID, OpId: OpId, option: option };

    if (this.state.Question.find((item) => item.OpId === OpId) !== undefined) {
      console.log("item exist");
    } else {
      console.log("item not exist");
      this.state.Question.push(Qobj);
    }
    console.log(this.state.Question);
}
```

when it come data like this {"QType":"Rating","QuesID":20,"OpId":2,"option":1}, need to remove if it has a value with "QuesID"=20 and add the new value coming with "QuesID"=20.
And also it will come data like below.

```
[{QType: "Rating", QuesID: "22", OpId: "4", option: "4"},
{QType: "Rating", QuesID: "23", OpId: "3", option: "3"},
{QType: "Rating", QuesID: "24", OpId: "2", option: "2"},
{QType: "Rating", QuesID: "25", OpId: "1", option: "1"}]
```

How can I fix this?

**Full Code**

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import fullStarSrc from "../img/highlightedStar.png";
    import emptyStarSrc from "../img/star.png";
    
    export default class testPage extends Component {
      state = {
        qtemp2: [
          { idsurveyquestion: "22", question: "Taste of the food?" },
          { idsurveyquestion: "23", question: "Quality of the food?" },
          { idsurveyquestion: "24", question: "Speed Of delivery?" },
          { idsurveyquestion: "25", question: "The accuracy of the order?" },
          { idsurveyquestion: "26", question: "How is our service?" },
        ],
        Question: [],
      };
    
      rate = (event, item) => {
        const { id } = event.target;
        var i;
        console.log("You clicked: " + id);
    
        var QType = "Rating";
        var QuesID = id.substr(1, 2);
        var OpId = id.charAt(0);
        var option = id.charAt(0);
        console.log(QuesID);
    
var Qobj = { QType: QType, QuesID: QuesID, OpId: OpId, option: option };

    if (
      this.state.Question.find((item) => item.QuesID === QuesID) !== undefined
    ) {
      console.log("item exist");
    } else {
      console.log("Not exist item");
      this.state.Question.push(Qobj);
    }

    // this.state.Question.push(Qobj);
    console.log(this.state.Question);
    
        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
          if (parseInt(i + item.idsurveyquestion) <= parseInt(id)) {
            document
              .getElementById(parseInt(i + item.idsurveyquestion))
              .setAttribute("src", fullStarSrc);
          } else {
            document
              .getElementById(parseInt(i + item.idsurveyquestion))
              .setAttribute("src", emptyStarSrc);
          }
        }
      };
    
      render() {
        const { qtemp2 } = this.state;
        return (
          <div>
            <div class="bg">
              <div class="bg_img1"></div>
              <div class="heading1">
                <center>
                  <h2 class="head1">Please Rate Us</h2>
                </center>
              </div>
              <center>
                <div>
                  {qtemp2.map((item) => (
                    <>
                      <p key={item.idsurveyquestion}>{item.question}</p>
                      <div>
                        <img
                          onClick={(event) => this.rate(event, item)}
                          class="star"
                          id={"1" + item.idsurveyquestion}
                          src={emptyStarSrc}
                        />
                        <img
                          onClick={(event) => this.rate(event, item)}
                          class="star"
                          id={"2" + item.idsurveyquestion}
                          src={emptyStarSrc}
                        />
                        <img
                          onClick={(event) => this.rate(event, item)}
                          class="star"
                          id={"3" + item.idsurveyquestion}
                          src={emptyStarSrc}
                        />
                        <img
                          onClick={(event) => this.rate(event, item)}
                          class="star"
                          id={"4" + item.idsurveyquestion}
                          src={emptyStarSrc}
                        />
                        <img
                          onClick={(event) => this.rate(event, item)}
                          class="star"
                          id={"5" + item.idsurveyquestion}
                          src={emptyStarSrc}
                        />
                      </div>
                    </>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </center>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

And also I need to unselect the all-stars when clicking on the same star. How can I do it with a simple variable like adding "let toRemove = false;" and Where Should I add "toRemove = true;" ?

This is what I tried-> https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-torvalds-j0995?file=/src/Rating2.js

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following (replace your `if else` block with this):

```
 const index = this.state.Question.findIndex((item) => item.OpId === OpId)
 const newArray = [...this.state.Question]
 if (index !== -1) {
   console.log("item exist");
   newArray.splice(index, 1, item)
 } else {
   console.log("item not exist");
   newArray.push(Qobj);
 }
 this.setState({ Question: newArray })
```

Comment: This is not working. If I put my full code, could you please help me?

Comment: @Sidath what is not working? Do you have any error?

Comment: No any error, Its not remove anything from the array. I add my Full code above. Please look at that.

Comment: @Sidath if you want to remove the item when it's found, then you need to edit the `splice` like this: `newArray.splice(index, 1)`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yeah right, But in my problem, for the first time there is no data in an array.  When clicking on the stars it will return some value to the object and push that data into the array. I need to remove an Item that is already exist and add a new value

Comment: You can check my full code to get an idea

Comment: @Sidath please make a `codesandbox` with your code. In this way I'll be able to help you.

Comment: Here I create a codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/embed/romantic-torvalds-j0995?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @Sidath is ok in this way https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-hooks-lkdvi?file=/src/Rating.js ?

Comment: Thanks for your support. I recreate my method with your options. Actually, I need the data set like in codesandbox that I provided now.  Could you please help me to unselect the all-stars when click on the same star with your code "let toRemove = false;". Where Should I add "toRemove = true;" this code line. Please help me with this. https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-torvalds-j0995?file=/src/Rating2.js

Answer (score 0):

first define some lists. one for checking Qtype and the other one for OpId, and etc:

```
let checkListQtype = [];
let checkListOpId = [];
```

then use this code:

```
let filteredData = YOURLIST.filter((item)=>{
if(checkListQtype.includes(item.QType) || checkListOpId.includes(item.OpId){
retrun false;
} else {
checkListQtype.push(item.QType);
checkListOpId.push(item.OpId);
return item;
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This login can help you.

1. find index of the item
2. then remove it
3. update state.

->

```
let questions = this.state.Question;
  const index = questions.findIndex(item=>item.OpId === OpId);
  if(index > -1){
    questions.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({Questions:arr})
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `QuesID` property of your objects is being used as a key which uniquely identifies the question. For this reason, it could make more sense to store your data not as an array, but as an object where the data is indexed by it's QuesID. This lets you very easily access, delete or modify the data for a known QuesID. For example:

```js
// state structured like this
{
  "22": {QType: "Rating", OpId: "4", option: "4"},
  "23": {QType: "Rating", OpId: "3", option: "3"},
  "24": {QType: "Rating", OpId: "2", option: "2"},
  "25": {QType: "Rating", OpId: "1", option: "1"}
}
```

```js
addData = (event, item) => {
    var QType = "Rating";
    var QuesID = "22";
    var OpId = "1";
    var option = "1";
    
    var Qobj = { QType: QType, OpId: OpId, option: option };

    this.setState({
        Question: {
            ...this.state.Question,
            [QuesID]: Qobj
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply use:

```
console.log(array.length)
```