# How to render array data one by one inside div tag in react js?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am creating a react app and getting all data from API calls. I have set data into an array and need to display them one by one inside the div tag.

**My data set is like below.**

```
qtemp3: [
  {
    idappcontent: "Sign_01",
    content:
      '<img id="vClub_logo" src="#FOLDERPATH#v-club.png" style="width:600px;height: 150px;">',
  },
  {
    idappcontent: "Sign_02",
    content:
      "<div style=\"color: #0D0D0D;\"> When you give us your name,<br /> e-mail address and the dates of your birthday and anniversary, we'll add you to our exclusive email database. You'll then be entitled to receive valuable offers each month and on those special occasions.</div>",
  },
  {
    idappcontent: "Sign_03",
    content:
      ' <div style="text-align:center"> <label for="firstName">First Name</label></div><div style="margin-top: 3%;"><input id="fname" name="firstName" onkeyup="FirstnameValidation()" style="font-family: trajanPro;width:100%;text-transform: capitalize;border-color: rgb(224, 94, 7);" /> </div>',
  },
  {
    idappcontent: "Sign_04",
    content:
      '<div style="text-align:center"> <label for="lname">Last Name</label> </div><div style="margin-top: 3%;"><input id="lname" name="lname" style="font-family: trajanPro;width:100%;text-transform: capitalize;" /></div>',
  },
  {
    idappcontent: "Sign_05",
    content:
      ' <div style="text-align:center"><label for="email">Email Address</label></div><div style="margin-top: 1%;"><input id="email" type="email" name="email" onkeyup="emailvalidation()"  style="width:100%;border-color: rgb(224, 94, 7);" /></div>',
  },
  {
    idappcontent: "Sign_06",
    content:
      '<div id="birthdayHeader"><label>Birthday</label></div><div style="display: inline-table; margin-top: 8px; width: 100%;"><div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; text-align: right"><label for="birthdayMonth">(Month)</label><input id="birthdayMonth" type="number" min="0" max="12" onkeyup = "birthdayMonthValidate()"  name="birthdayMonth" style="width:45px"></div><div style="display:inline-block;width:50%;text-align:left"><input id="birthdayDay" type="number" min="0" max="31" name="birthdayDay" onkeyup = "birthdayValidate()" style="width:45px"><label for="birthdayDay">(Day)</label></div></div></div>',
  },
],
```

Now I need to render this array inside the div tag.

**My div tag codes are like below.**

```
<div class="Header-banner" style="text-align: center;" id="Sign_01"></div>
<div id="Sign_02"></div>
<div id="signUpfrm" style="width:100%">
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <div style="display:inline-table;width:100%">
            <div id="Sign_03" style="display: inline-block; text-align: right; width: 32%;margin-right: 1px;"></div>
            <div id="Sign_04" style="display: inline-block; text-align: left; width: 32%; margin-left: 2px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="Sign_05" style="margin-top: 2%; width: 65%; display: inline-table;"></div>

        <div id="Sign_09" class="MainWrapper" style="margin-top: 2%; width: 65%; display: inline-table;"></div>
        <div style="display:inline-flex; width: 89%;">
            <div id="Sign_07" class="MainWrapper" style="width:50%"></div>
            <div id="Sign_08" class="Mainwrapper" style="width: 50%; margin-top: 8px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 28px; margin-top: 4%">
            <div id="Sign_06" class="MainWrapper" style="margin-top: 4%;"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

How to display array data one by one inside this div tags?

Comment: dude explain more also which part of div you want to display?

Comment: any relation with reactjs?

Comment: There is a id like" idappcontent: "Sign_01", data in the array. I need to display them in `<div class="Header-banner" style="text-align: center;" id="Sign_01"></div>`

Comment: Likewise need to display the data in the correct idappconten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use map

```
qtemp3.map(item=>{
document.getElementById(item.idappcontent).innerHTML=item.content
});
```

Here is the sample:

```js
const qtemp3= [
  {
    idappcontent: "Sign_01",
    content:
      '<img id="vClub_logo" src="#FOLDERPATH#v-club.png" style="width:600px;height: 150px;">',
  },
  {
    idappcontent: "Sign_02",
    content:
      "<div style=\"color: #0D0D0D;\"> When you give us your name,<br /> e-mail address and the dates of your birthday and anniversary, we'll add you to our exclusive email database. You'll then be entitled to receive valuable offers each month and on those special occasions.</div>",
  },
  {
    idappcontent: "Sign_03",
    content:
      ' <div style="text-align:center"> <label for="firstName">First Name</label></div><div style="margin-top: 3%;"><input id="fname" name="firstName" onkeyup="FirstnameValidation()" style="font-family: trajanPro;width:100%;text-transform: capitalize;border-color: rgb(224, 94, 7);" /> </div>',
  },
  {
    idappcontent: "Sign_04",
    content:
      '<div style="text-align:center"> <label for="lname">Last Name</label> </div><div style="margin-top: 3%;"><input id="lname" name="lname" style="font-family: trajanPro;width:100%;text-transform: capitalize;" /></div>',
  },
  {
    idappcontent: "Sign_05",
    content:
      ' <div style="text-align:center"><label for="email">Email Address</label></div><div style="margin-top: 1%;"><input id="email" type="email" name="email" onkeyup="emailvalidation()"  style="width:100%;border-color: rgb(224, 94, 7);" /></div>',
  },
  {
    idappcontent: "Sign_06",
    content:
      '<div id="birthdayHeader"><label>Birthday</label></div><div style="display: inline-table; margin-top: 8px; width: 100%;"><div style="display: inline-block; width: 50%; text-align: right"><label for="birthdayMonth">(Month)</label><input id="birthdayMonth" type="number" min="0" max="12" onkeyup = "birthdayMonthValidate()"  name="birthdayMonth" style="width:45px"></div><div style="display:inline-block;width:50%;text-align:left"><input id="birthdayDay" type="number" min="0" max="31" name="birthdayDay" onkeyup = "birthdayValidate()" style="width:45px"><label for="birthdayDay">(Day)</label></div></div></div>',
  },
];

qtemp3.map(item=>{
document.getElementById(item.idappcontent).innerHTML=item.content
});
```

```html
<div class="Header-banner" style="text-align: center;" id="Sign_01"></div>
<div id="Sign_02"></div>
<div id="signUpfrm" style="width:100%">
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <div style="display:inline-table;width:100%">
            <div id="Sign_03" style="display: inline-block; text-align: right; width: 32%;margin-right: 1px;"></div>
            <div id="Sign_04" style="display: inline-block; text-align: left; width: 32%; margin-left: 2px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="Sign_05" style="margin-top: 2%; width: 65%; display: inline-table;"></div>

        <div id="Sign_09" class="MainWrapper" style="margin-top: 2%; width: 65%; display: inline-table;"></div>
        <div style="display:inline-flex; width: 89%;">
            <div id="Sign_07" class="MainWrapper" style="width:50%"></div>
            <div id="Sign_08" class="Mainwrapper" style="width: 50%; margin-top: 8px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 28px; margin-top: 4%">
            <div id="Sign_06" class="MainWrapper" style="margin-top: 4%;"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and here is react js sample:

[React Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-cray-ibrc3)

Comment: i was gonna do that but idk what hes trying to loop

Comment: BTW SAME POINTS

Comment: @Ahmad Rahmani, Where should I place this code line -> `qtemp3.map(item=>{
document.getElementById(item.idappcontent).innerHTML=item.content
});`

Comment: Please help me. I am new to react

Comment: @Ahmad Rahmani Please help to fix my code with your answer. I don't have good knowledge of react js. Please add Full React code. I'm trying adding your code in some places. but it gives me an error.

Comment: I updated the answer and added react sample, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank You so much. I'll try this.

Comment: Dear Ahmad Rahmani, could you please help me to complete my project? I'm totally new to react js. If you can please give me your email or anything that I can contact you.

Comment: Dear Ahmad Rahmani, I had another question and I post it in  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68678978/how-to-check-if-a-value-already-exists-in-an-array-and-remove-that-from-array-in) here.

Comment: I wanted to unselect the star when clicking on the same star and need to remove it from the data array. This is what I tried. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-torvalds-j0995?file=/src/Rating2.js).

Comment: If there is a way to Make a variable to true when clicking on the same star or any other way to fix this problem, please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand your code but your data should look like this:

```
const qtemp3 = [
  {
   idappcontent: "Sign_01",
   content: '#FOLDERPATH#v-club.png'
  },
]
```

and your gonna display it:

```
<p>{qtemp3.idappcontent}</p>
<img id="vClub_logo" src={qtemp3.content} style="width:600px;height: 150px;" />,
```

if you want to learn more about it check this website:

https://scotch.io/courses/10-react-challenges-beginner/display-simple-data-with-jsx

dont do the challenges just check the answers and they explain it well

***FULL CODE:***

```
    {data.map((item) => (

<div class="Header-banner" style="text-align: center;" id="Sign_01"></div>
<div id="Sign_02"></div>
<div id="signUpfrm" style="width:100%">
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <div style="display:inline-table;width:100%">
            <div id="Sign_03" style="display: inline-block; text-align: right; width: 32%;margin-right: 1px;"></div>
            <div id="Sign_04" style="display: inline-block; text-align: left; width: 32%; margin-left: 2px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="Sign_05" style="margin-top: 2%; width: 65%; display: inline-table;"></div>

        <div id="Sign_09" class="MainWrapper" style="margin-top: 2%; width: 65%; display: inline-table;"></div>
        <div style="display:inline-flex; width: 89%;">
            <div id="Sign_07" class="MainWrapper" style="width:50%"></div>
            <div id="Sign_08" class="Mainwrapper" style="width: 50%; margin-top: 8px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 28px; margin-top: 4%">
            <div id="Sign_06" class="MainWrapper" style="margin-top: 4%;"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

    )}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just show `n` elements with same style it's with `.map`

```
<div>
{qtemp3.map(item => (
//component you like to show n times, item is your variable for each element
{item.component}
))}
</div>
```